# how to run task scheduling locally nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I want to execute the cron in nestjs locally and I have not found a way to test the cron locally.

example:

```
import { Cron } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(TasksService.name);

  @Cron('45 * * * * *')
  handleCron() {
    this.logger.debug('Called when the current second is 45');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service looks fine, you just need to activate it.

To activate job scheduling, import the ScheduleModule into the root AppModule and run the forRoot() static method as shown below:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ScheduleModule } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ScheduleModule.forRoot()
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Source](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#installation)